# React Native flexDirection bug?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I just stared with react native and play arround. So I just tryed the `flexDirection` style.

So I copyed the example from [facebook-react](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html) and it looks good.

Code I testet and the webside and in the Expo app

```
enter code here
  <View style={{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  }}>
    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
    <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
  </View>
```

for `flexDirection: 'row'` in looks on my iPhone (expo App) the same. But if i chance it to `column` my screen is just white (the View elements disappears?). 
Next thing I tryed is to set `justifyContent: 'center'` after i Did this it look like the Image I append, super wird, if you test it at the facebook page it should be obv be centered...

[image: screenshot]

So is this a bug? What is my mistake there?

This is the hole thing...:

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NativeRouter>
        <View>
          <Route exact path='/'>
              <View style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                  justifyContent: 'center'
              }}>
                  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
                  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
                  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
              </View>
          </Route>
        </View>
      </NativeRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you remove the first View tag, it will work fine. I tested on React native web site. This happens because your first view doesn't fit all your screen. You can revome the first View tag, or set the flex for it.

You can check Route too.

```js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NativeRouter>
        <View style={{
             flex: 1
         }}>
          <Route exact path='/'>
              <View style={{
                  flex: 1,
                  flexDirection: 'column',
                  justifyContent: 'center'
              }}>
                  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
                  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
                  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
              </View>
          </Route>
        </View>
      </NativeRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Im new to react native, so thank you very mush for you help :)

Answer (score 2):

I usually have this issue, you may have to add a `flex:1` on the parent view so it will full up the screen, then the flex-directions should look right.